# Convert a date range to Date type in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This vector of date ranges is included in a dataframe of mine with class 'character'. The formats vary depending on whether the date range crosses into a different month:

```
dput(pollingdata$dates)
c("Nov. 1-7", "Nov. 1-7", "Oct. 24-Nov. 6", "Oct. 4-Nov. 6", 
"Oct. 30-Nov. 6", "Oct. 25-31", "Oct. 7-27", "Oct. 21-Nov. 3", 
"Oct. 20-24", "Jul. 19", "Oct. 29-Nov. 4", "Oct. 28-Nov. 3", 
"Oct. 27-Nov. 2", "Oct. 20-28", "Sep. 30-Oct. 20", "Oct. 15-19", 
"Oct. 26-Nov. 1", "Oct. 25-31", "Oct. 24-30", "Oct. 18-26", 
"Oct. 10-14", "Oct. 4-9", "Sep. 23-Oct. 6", "Sep. 16-29", "Sep. 2-22", 
"Oct. 21-Nov. 2", "Oct. 17-25", "Sep. 30-Oct. 13", "Sep. 27-Oct. 3", 
"Sep. 21-26", "Sep. 14-20", "Aug. 26-Sep. 15", "Sep. 7-13", 
"Aug. 19-Sep. 8", "Aug. 31-Sep. 6", "Aug. 12-Sep. 1", "Aug. 9-Sep. 1", 
"Aug. 24-30", "Aug. 5-25", "Aug. 17-23", "Jul. 29-Aug. 18", 
"Aug. 10-16", "Jan. 12")
```

I would like to convert this vector into two separate columns in my dataframe, 1. startdate and 2. enddate, for the beginning and end of the range. Both columns should be saved as class 'Date', this will make it easier for me to use the data in my project. Does anyone know an easy way to do this manipulation? I have been struggling with it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the vector by `-` into a `list`, replace the elements that have only numbers at the end by `paste`ing the month substring, append NA for those having less than 2 elements using (`length<-`) and convert to `data.frame` (with `do.call(rbind.data.frame`)

```
lst <- lapply(strsplit(v1, "-"), function(x) {
       i1 <- grepl("^[0-9]+", x[length(x)])
         if(i1) {
            x[length(x)] <- paste(substr(x[1], 1, 4), x[length(x)])
          x} else x})
d1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
colnames(d1) <- c("Start_Date", "End_Date")
```

As per the OP's post, we need to convert to `Date` class, but `Date` class follows the `format` of `%Y-%m-%d`.  In the vector, there is no year, not sure we can paste the current year and convert to `Date` class. If that is permissible, then

```
d1[] <-  lapply(d1, function(x) as.Date(paste(x, 2017), "%b. %d %Y"))
head(d1)
#  Start_Date   End_Date
#1 2017-11-01 2017-11-07
#2 2017-11-01 2017-11-07
#3 2017-10-24 2017-11-06
#4 2017-10-04 2017-11-06
#5 2017-10-30 2017-11-06
#6 2017-10-25 2017-10-31
```

Comment: this works great, let me dig into it. the columns aren't Date format but I may be able to get that

Comment: @Canovice  Date requires year info, in your dataset it is not shown.  If you can paste some random year, then it gets convert to `Date` (showed in the update)

Answer (score 1):

You may use library `stringr` function "**str_split_fixed**" to split the fields and then process the data. Map the library stringr and process as below:

```
library(stringr)
    dat <- data.frame(date=c("Nov. 1-7", "Nov. 1-7", "Oct. 24-Nov. 6", "Oct. 4-Nov. 6", 
              "Oct. 30-Nov. 6", "Oct. 25-31", "Oct. 7-27", "Oct. 21-Nov. 3", 
              "Oct. 20-24", "Jul. 19", "Oct. 29-Nov. 4", "Oct. 28-Nov. 3", 
              "Oct. 27-Nov. 2", "Oct. 20-28", "Sep. 30-Oct. 20", "Oct. 15-19", 
              "Oct. 26-Nov. 1", "Oct. 25-31", "Oct. 24-30", "Oct. 18-26", 
              "Oct. 10-14", "Oct. 4-9", "Sep. 23-Oct. 6", "Sep. 16-29", "Sep. 2-22", 
              "Oct. 21-Nov. 2", "Oct. 17-25", "Sep. 30-Oct. 13", "Sep. 27-Oct. 3", 
              "Sep. 21-26", "Sep. 14-20", "Aug. 26-Sep. 15", "Sep. 7-13", 
              "Aug. 19-Sep. 8", "Aug. 31-Sep. 6", "Aug. 12-Sep. 1", "Aug. 9-Sep. 1", 
              "Aug. 24-30", "Aug. 5-25", "Aug. 17-23", "Jul. 29-Aug. 18", 
              "Aug. 10-16", "Jan. 12"))
```

**Output processing:**

```
#spliting with space and dash
dt <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(dat$date, "[-]|\\s",4))
names(dt) <- c("stdt1","stdt2","endt1","endt2")
##Removing dot(.) and replacing with ""
dt1 <- data.frame(sapply(dt,function(x)gsub("[.]","",x)))
dt1$stdt <- as.Date(paste0(dt1$stdt2,dt1$stdt1,"2016"),format="%d%b%Y")
dt1$endt <- ifelse(dt1$endt2=="",paste0(dt1$endt1,dt1$stdt1,"2016"),
              paste0(dt1$endt2,dt1$endt1,"2016"))

dt1$endt <-as.Date(ifelse(nchar(dt1$endt)==7,paste0(dt1$stdt2,dt1$endt),dt1$endt),"%d%b%Y")
```

**Assumptions:**

1) No year provided , hence I have taken year as 2016.

2) On 10th row and 43rd row, there is no info on end date "day",hence I have assumed the same day as start date.

**Answer:**

```
> dt1
   stdt1 stdt2 endt1 endt2       stdt       endt
1    Nov     1     7       2016-11-01 2016-11-07
2    Nov     1     7       2016-11-01 2016-11-07
3    Oct    24   Nov     6 2016-10-24 2016-11-06
4    Oct     4   Nov     6 2016-10-04 2016-11-06
5    Oct    30   Nov     6 2016-10-30 2016-11-06
6    Oct    25    31       2016-10-25 2016-10-31
7    Oct     7    27       2016-10-07 2016-10-27
8    Oct    21   Nov     3 2016-10-21 2016-11-03
9    Oct    20    24       2016-10-20 2016-10-24
10   Jul    19             2016-07-19 2016-07-19
```